# How to visualize data to a box-plot using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I managed to calculate the correlation and visualize the data in the form of a scatter-plot using matplotlib between data_1 and other data well, but I am confused about how to visualize it in the form of a Box-plot because I don't understand the basic principle of the box-plot itself, how to do it with matplotlib?

```
data_1 = [19.2, 18.3, 17.1, 15.2, 14.0, 13.8, 12.8, 17.3, 16.3, 16.0, 15.7, 15.3, 14.3, 14.0, 13.8, 12.5, 11.5, 14.2, 17.3, 15.8]
data_2 = [3.85, 3.75, 3.88, 3.66, 3.47, 3.75, 3.92, 3.97, 3.76, 3.98, 3.75, 3.77, 3.76, 3.76, 3.9, 3.8, 3.65, 3.6, 3.86, 3.93]
data_3 = [66.0, 79.0, 73.0, 86.0, 178.0, 108.0, 96.0, 59.0, 22.0, 58.0, 120.0, 144.0, 100.0, 104.0, 67.0, 89.0, 192.0, 301.0, 99.0, 66.0]
data_4 = [9.35, 11.15, 9.4, 6.4, 3.6, 5.8, 5.0, 10.25, 8.2, 10.15, 8.8, 5.6, 5.55, 8.7, 7.41, 5.35, 6.35, 4.25, 12.85, 4.9]
data_5 = [5.65, 6.92, 5.75, 4.0, 2.25, 3.2, 2.7, 6.1, 5.0, 6.0, 5.5, 3.35, 3.25, 5.1, 4.4, 3.15, 3.9, 2.4, 7.7, 2.75]
```

Comment: scatter plot shows you relationship _between_ variables. box plot shows you the spread _within_ a variable.

Comment: @tdy may I add your comment on my answer?

Comment: @user1740577 sure, feel free

Comment: _"because I don't understand the basic principle of the box-plot itself"_. There's plenty of resources online for reading about what a box plot is. Perhaps start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot

Answer (score 1):

by thanks of @tdy :*scatter plot shows you the relationship between variables but box plot shows you the spread within a variable.*

For visualizing data in the form of a Box-plot you can try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


data_1 = [19.2, 18.3, 17.1, 15.2, 14.0, 13.8, 12.8, 17.3, 16.3, 16.0, 15.7, 15.3, 14.3, 14.0, 13.8, 12.5, 11.5, 14.2, 17.3, 15.8]
data_2 = [3.85, 3.75, 3.88, 3.66, 3.47, 3.75, 3.92, 3.97, 3.76, 3.98, 3.75, 3.77, 3.76, 3.76, 3.9, 3.8, 3.65, 3.6, 3.86, 3.93]
data_3 = [66.0, 79.0, 73.0, 86.0, 178.0, 108.0, 96.0, 59.0, 22.0, 58.0, 120.0, 144.0, 100.0, 104.0, 67.0, 89.0, 192.0, 301.0, 99.0, 66.0]
data_4 = [9.35, 11.15, 9.4, 6.4, 3.6, 5.8, 5.0, 10.25, 8.2, 10.15, 8.8, 5.6, 5.55, 8.7, 7.41, 5.35, 6.35, 4.25, 12.85, 4.9]
data_5 = [5.65, 6.92, 5.75, 4.0, 2.25, 3.2, 2.7, 6.1, 5.0, 6.0, 5.5, 3.35, 3.25, 5.1, 4.4, 3.15, 3.9, 2.4, 7.7, 2.75] 


data = [data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4, data_5]
 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))
 
bp = ax.boxplot(data)
 
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]